# stayed up all night studying / to study

Tags: grammar

**"I was so worried about today's exam that I stayed up all night studying."**

This is a sentence from the exam in my school. Can the sentence be changed to **"I was so worried about today's exam that I stayed up all night to study."**? Will they mean the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practical usage, they might communicate the same thing. However, the words themselves don't have the same meaning:

> I was so worried about today's exam that I stayed up all night studying.

This means that you spent all night actually engaged in studying. This describes what you did while awake.

> I was so worried about today's exam that I stayed up all night to study.

This means that you stayed up all night with the *intention* of studying. But whether or not you *actually* studied, or how much of the night was taken up with studying, is unknown. This only talks about *why* you stayed up all night.